# UIImagePickerViewController of custom frame size

Tags: ios, camera, uiimagepickercontroller, ios-camera

On my app, I am trying to initialise and present a `UIImagePickerViewController` instance of custom size. Basically, I want a square view of size 200x200 to hover over my viewController. I tried out the following code and it still presents the camera overlay in full-screen mode. Any suggestions on how I can achieve a custom frame on my overlay view?

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imagePickerController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
imagePickerController.delegate = self;                                          imagePickerController.showsCameraControls = NO;
imagePickerController.cameraOverlayView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)];
[self presentViewController:imagePickerController animated:NO completion:nil];
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need use `cameraOverlayView` property. Set to this property your custom view that contains transparent square of size 200x200.

Notice to code that you've provided:
When you create view `[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)];` it uses clear (transparent) colour by default. That's why you don't see it after launching.
Change it's background colour and it will become visible over the camera layer:

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)];
view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
imagePickerController.cameraOverlayView = view;
```

Comment: Ah. Maybe I misunderstood the concept of the overlay view. I want the view that displays the live feed of the camera itself to be of frame 200x200.

Comment: @RameezHussain UIImagePickerController provides camera layer (live feed) by default. And by default it fills full screen. But as you want camera layer with size 200x200 then you need provide `overlayView` that will overlap all area except 200x200 frame. In other words: overlayView - is view that added on the top of camera layer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at Face Detection enabling for ios and its API in Apple developer library.
CoreImageFramework provides the API where on detection you can hover .
CIImageFilter, CIFilter methods are used

for Reference please read Apple Documentation and Check the following sample

Square Cam

Using UIImagePIckerController Its Difficult to overlay and Hover on move , Use AVFoundation framework for better Results